# Changing xDateFormat in highchart tooltip programatically

Tags: highcharts

I'm attempting to change the my tooltip xDateFormat programmatically.  I'm currently calling:

```
chart.tooltip.options.xDateFormat = getDateFormatString(newValue.timeInterval);
chart.redraw();
```

However, that's not doing what I need it to do.  I'm playing around with this jsfiddle (pardon my lack of knowledge of jquery, I'm currently writing in angular).

http://jsfiddle.net/2ET8j/

Thanks!

Comment: Here's an example that changes the tooltip formatter instead of changing the xDateFormat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479476/change-highcharts-tooltip-formatter-from-chart-object-after-chart-is-rendered.

Comment: Yes, I actually made my jsfiddle off of a fork of that working on. I couldn't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that changes the formatter instead of trying to change the xDateFormat. http://jsfiddle.net/eyyH6/

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');    
    chart.tooltip.options.formatter = function() {
        var s = '<b>'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e %Y %H:%M', this.x, true) +'</b>';


        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
            s += '<br/>'+ point.series.name +': '+
                point.y +'m';
        });

        return s;
    }
});
```

EDIT:
An undocumented way to change the xDateFormat

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');    
    chart.series[0].tooltipOptions.xDateFormat = '%b %e %Y %H:%M';
});
```

Comment: See my last comment: I used this exact jsfiddle to jumpstart how to change xDateFormat.  I would rather use the dateFormatter rather than the function formatter.  Is there anyway to do similar with xDateFormatter.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you didn't know how to change the dateFormat with the formatter function.  So this code ilustrates that.  The original changed the format of the points and removed the x point display from the tooltip.  I don't think you can change the xDateFormat without redisplaying the data.  So, the formatter option is the better choice.

Comment: Actually, I found an undocumented way to do it.  See the updated answer. Use at your own risk :)

Comment: Oh man, yeah. I'll try it.  It's always so counter intuitive.